# Menu option read aloud not working

Tags: java, google-glass

I am trying to make a read aloud menu option here. This is the code I have written. But it doesn't really read aloud the text on the card. The doc says that if there is any text set on the card it will read aloud. My card has some text on it :

`newcard.setText("text");`

My `MenuActivity` which is called looks like this.

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    public Object json(int menuid)
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            System.out.println("goes into try of json");
            obj.put("text", "Hello World");
            obj.put("menuItems", new JSONObject().put("action", "READ_ALOUD"));
            System.out.println(obj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        openOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.read_aloud_menu_item:
                System.out.println("goes itno read aloud case");
                json(item.getItemId());

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
        // Nothing else to do, closing the activity.
        finish();
    }
}
```

I am really not sure wheteher I can pass the JSON like this. If not like this, how else can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you read that Glass would automatically read this aloud...

You should use `TextToSpeech` as in the [gdk-compass-sample](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-compass-sample/blob/master/src/com/google/android/glass/sample/compass/CompassService.java) provided by Google.

Create a field in your `Activity`

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
  private TextToSpeech mSpeech;
  ...
}
```

Initialise in `OnCreate`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ...
    mSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    });
}
```

Call the `speak` function in your `onOptionsItemSelected` event

```
mSpeech.speak(json(item.getItemId()).text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Close everything down in the `onDestroy` event

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mSpeech.shutdown();
    mSpeech = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but what is text in
mSpeech.speak(json(item.getItemId()).text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
Its giving an error so its not the text in obj.put("text", "Hello World");

Comment: What error does it throw? Try: mSpeech.speak("hello", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); If this works check why you don't get the right text... If you want to know what it exactly does, first go dive into the documentations, if you don't get it, ask your question here.

Comment: Okay, i tried as suggested, it doesn't even read the "hello". I will surely go through the documenatation for further insight.